# One value constructor belonging to two different types

Tags: haskell, types

Let's say I have three value constructors:

```
A { a :: Int }
B { b :: Char }
C { c :: Bool }
```

I would like to create two types `X` and `Y` such that a value of type `X` can be an `A`, `B` or `C`, something like this:

```
data X = A {...} | B {...} | C {...}
```

and a value of type `Y` can be only an `A` or `B`, something like this:

```
data Y = A {...} | B {...}
```

so that I can code something like this:

```
foo :: X -> Int -- can pattern match
foo (A _) = 1
foo (B _) = 2
foo (C _) = 3
bar :: Y -> Bool -- also can pattern match with the same constructors
bar (A _) = true
bar (B _) = false
baz = A 1 -- baz is inferred to be a type that can fit in both X and Y
```

I know that I can wrap the constructors in the definitions of `X` and `Y` like this:

```
data X = XA A | XB B | XC C
data Y = YA A | YB B
```

but this seems untidy (having to type `XA A` etc. all the time). I could expand the contents of `A`, `B`, and `C` into the definitions of `X` and `Y`, but `A` etc. are quite complicated and I would prefer not to duplicate the definition.

Is this possible with Haskell, including any GHC extensions?

**Edit**

It seems that GADTs can answer my question as asked (so I marked heatsink's answer as correct), but still aren't flexible enough for what I need. For example, as far as I know, you can't do something like:

```
func1 :: [XY Y_] -- returns a list of items that can only be A or B
func1 = ...
func2 = func1 ++ [C True] -- adding a C item to the list
```

`func2` should be typed as `[XY X_]`, but that isn't possible in Haskell (unless my experiment was wrong).

After more web searching, what I really want is OCaml's polymorphic variants which (as far as I know) exist only in OCaml (looking at the more "practical" as opposed to "academic" languages).

**Edit 2**

See comonad's answer. It seems that it really can be done, but I think I'd better not rewrite this question too many times. :-)

Comment: Your definitions for `foo` and `bar` won't type check, because `A _` is by definition a value of type `A`, not `X` or `Y`. You cannot have another type (`X`) with the same constructor.

Comment: Another way to look at it: what type would `A` have?  It can only have one, so it can't be `Int -> X` and `Int -> Y` simultaneously.

Comment: jetxee and Antal S-Z: I know that my definitions of `foo` and `bar` won't typecheck, but I was hoping that something similar would be valid Haskell. For example, with typeclasses, `read x` (where `x` is a `String`) can have (in a sense) more than one type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type classes, as [jetxee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256502/one-value-constructor-belonging-to-two-different-types/4256813#4256813) described, are probably the appropriate approach.

If you also want the ability to pattern match and use constructors, then you can define all the constructors within one data type using GADTs and empty data declarations.  If you take this approach, all the constructors will be members of the same data type, while letting you restrict the domain to only a subset of the constructors.

```
data X_
data Y_
data XY a where
  A :: Int -> XY a
  B :: Char -> XY a
  C :: Bool -> XY X_
type X = XY X_ -- Contains values built with constructors A, B, and C 
type Y = XY Y_ -- Contains only values built with constructors A and B
```

Now a function that uses only `A` and `B` works with both types `X` and `Y`.  A function that uses `C` will work only with type `X`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at GADTs and see if they are what I need.

Answer (score 5):

```
baz = A 1 -- baz is inferred to be a type that can fit in both X and Y
```

This would require Haskell to support some form of subtyping, which it does not. There are no ghc extensions that enable this either.

The best thing you can do is probably something like this:

```
data Y = A ... | B ...
data X = XY Y | C ...
```

This way you don't have to repeat the constructors `A` and `B` and you don't have to write `Y (A foo)` either - you can just write `A foo` to get a value of type `Y`.

However you will have to write `X (A foo)` to get a value of type `X` which contains an `A`. This isn't quite what you want, but the closest you will get, I'm afraid.

Comment: Indeed, by "definition" an object as one and only one "type" as opposed to class. Or if you prefer type sets are a partition of the set of all "object" in Haskell

Comment: Hmm...yeah I guess I was hoping for something better than this. Maybe GADTs (another answer suggested this) would be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Your definitions for `foo` and `bar` won't type check, because `A _` is by definition a value of type `A`, not `X` or `Y`. You cannot have another type (`X`) with the same constructor. So, the correct thing is what you've written:

```
data X = XA A | XB B | XC C
data Y = YA A | YB B
```

But let's approach it from another perspective. *Why* do you need that? You want to express, that `X` can be either, `A`, `B`, or `C`, and `Y` can be either `A` or `B`. You don't care about values of `A`, `B` and `C` respectively. So *being `A`* and *being `B`* are features common to both `X` and `Y`.

When you have a common trait beteen two types (`X` and `Y` in this case), you can often **express it with type classes**. Please note that type classes are open, so as many types can implement them as you like.

For example, we can define three type classes which allow to check if the type has `A`, `B` or `C`:

```
class HasA t where hasA :: t -> Bool
class HasB t where hasB :: t -> Bool
class HasC t where hasC :: t -> Bool
```

Now for our types we still have to use distinct data constructors:

```
data A = A Int
data B = B Char
data C = C Bool
data X = XA A | XB B | XC C
data Y = YA A | YB B
```

But we can define class instances both for `X` and for `Y`:

```
instance HasA X where
  hasA (XA _) = True
  hasA _ = False
instance HasB X where 
  hasB (XB _) = True
  hasB _ = False
instance HasC X where
  hasC (XC _) = True
  hasC _ = False

instance HasA Y where 
  hasA (YA _) = True
  hasA _ = False
instance HasB Y where 
  hasB (YB _) = True
  hasB _ = False
instance HasC Y where 
  hasC = const False
```

With these type classes you can write `foo` and `bar` which accept both `X`s and `Y`s.

```
foo :: (HasA t, HasB t, HasC t) => t -> Int
foo v | hasA v = 1
      | hasB v = 2
      | hasC v = 3
      | otherwise = undefined
bar :: (HasA t, HasB t) => t -> Bool
bar v | hasA v = True
      | hasB v = False
      | otherwise = undefined

xs = [ XA (A 1), XB (B '1'), XC (C True) ]
ys = [ YA (A 1), YB (B '1') ]
```

More precisely, `foo` accepts *anything* which implements `HasA`, `HasB` and `HasC`, and `bar` accepts *anything* which implements `HasA` and `HasB` (whether or not `HasC` is implemented is irrelevant in the context of `bar`). If the implementation happens to return `False` in every case, then `foo` and `bar` are undefined.

For example:

```
ghci> map foo xs
[1,2,3]
ghci> map foo ys
[1,2]
ghci> map bar xs
[True,False,*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
ghci> map bar ys
[True,False]
```

Please note that `bar` accepts also `X`s, but it is undefined if it happens to be something else except `A` or `B`. You as a programmer, not the compiler, are responsible to think about exhaustiveness of the guards in this case.

If you need also the values of `A`, `B` and `C`, then you have to design the type classes differently, e.g. like

```
class HasA t where getA :: t -> Maybe A
```

but the idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks. I've thought of this but thought that I couldn't pattern match against the various types (XA,YA) that satisfy the typeclass (HasA), but I didn't think about guards. However I do need the values of A, B, and C, and probably this solution would be as verbose as (if not more) than the original XA and YA idea.

Answer (score 1):

Using Heatsink's answer, I kame up with this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs,EmptyDataDecls #-}
module Test where


data NotThatY
data XY a where
  A :: Int -> XY a
  B :: Char -> XY a
  C :: Bool -> XY NotThatY

type Y a = XY a
type X a = XY NotThatY -- or type X =..., but (X a) looks better alongside (Y a).

func1 :: [Y a]
func1 = [A 5, B 'ö']
func2 :: [X a]
func2 = func1 ++ [C True]
```

The restriction to *Y* is removed. Now it works, but it looks somehow strange with that *a* in the type.

`type Y = forall a. XY a` -- does not work.