# Use one Data Constructor into two different Types

Tags: haskell, types

Now I'm trying to write a toy-language-frontend using Haskell.

And there are two entities:

- rvalue - variables and integer-literals (for example)
- lvalue - variables only.

I think the most natural way to describe this in data structures is:

```
data LValue = Var String
data RValue = Var String | Lit Int
```

(I really think this is the best approach - not verbose and strict enough thanks exhaustive pattern matching)
But ghc shows me error: "multiple declarations of Var".

So the question is: what's the most straightforward way in Haskell to describe what I want?

Noteces:
There is a similar question 11 years ago with no good answer. But has anything changed for 11 years?
[One value constructor belonging to two different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256502/one-value-constructor-belonging-to-two-different-types)

And there is some other approaches with "packing" LValue again (and again and again in less-toy-language) in data-constructor like this:

```
data LValue = Var String 
data RValue = LValue LValue | Lit Int
```

But I doubt is this good way: AST-transformation code becomes too verbose.

Comment: how about `data RValue = LValue | Lit Int`?

Comment: hm.... it better than i though (and I miss this approach)

But is  LValue really subset of RValue (this is too important question in my opinion)?

Comment: I just went wit the definition you gave at the beginning. rvalues: variables and literals, lvalues: variables only.

Comment: With what you want, using two types, how are you supposed to know what type `Var "x"` is? A variable may be able to *serve* as an lvalue, but it's not a kind of lvalue. You are conflating properties *of* your language with the objects you can represent *with* your language.

Comment: This is undoubtfully good idea (and better than I cat find out in myself). 

But I wonder is it "just good" or "best of all"?
If in "program languages" RValue really "LValue and some other kind of values" - it's "best of all", and question cat be closed.

If it isn't - i'll try find solution where "subject area objects matches 1:1 on data types"

Comment: >> With what you want, using two types, how are you supposed to know what type Var "x" is?

Good question.
It's semantic properties - and honestly I don't (didn't at least before now) suppose express semantic properties in data types, only in explicit AST-checkers.

Comment: No, you don't want two types: you'll have a data structure for an assignment statement; it'll allow only a `Var` on its lhs; it'll also allow `Var`(s) on its rhs. As your language gets more advanced, you'll want to allow certain expressions to appear on lhs also -- such as an array subscript with an index expression. So lhs vs rhs is not about the syntax of the term, it's about its _semantics_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually think your proposal is the best:

```
newtype LValue = Var String -- newtype is slightly better here, I think
data RValue = LValue LValue | Lit Int
```

It is almost certainly the case that any time you use an lvalue as an rvalue, you want to treat all lvalues in a uniform way, so you likely won't need or want to do a second level of pattern matching at that moment; in other words, I claim there will be less verbosity than you might expect at first.

There are basically two alternatives. The first is to make a class:

```
newtype LValue = LVar String
data RValue = RVar String | Lit Int

class HasVariables ty where var :: String -> ty
instance HasVariables LValue where var = LVar
instance HasVariables RValue where var = RVar
```

This way you can use `var` for constructing either `LValue`s or `RValue`s. You will still need to distinguish between them syntactically when pattern-matching though.

The second is to make a GADT:

```
data Side = L | R
data Value side where
    Var :: String -> Value side
    Lit :: String -> Value R
```

Comment: >> It is almost certainly the case that any time you use an lvalue as an rvalue, you want to treat all lvalues in a uniform way

Thank you and @user1984. Honestly I havn't thought about this before, and now I realized, that this is a case (in a large-scale question about LValue and RValue).